# Sorting data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

OK, obviously my first explanation of this was not clear... I wasn't exactly sure what to say. To simplify, what do I need to do to use the form below to successfully search in the mysql database I have?  I want to have the user select from the three options in the dropdown menu and then type in the text to search and get the results that match from that category displayed.

html file:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>Database Search</h2>

    <form action="retrieve_data.php" method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='submitted'>
    Search for your information:
    <select name="field" id="field">
    <option value="id">id</option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
    <option value="username">username</option>
    </select>
    Search item:<input type="text" name='cond' size='20'><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

php code I currently have that searches using checkboxes, which I don't want:

```
 <?php 

 extract($_REQUEST); 

 $fields = 0; 
 $query = "select "; 
 $th = ""; 
 for( $i = 0; $i < count($chk); $i++ )  { 
 if( $chk[$i] )  { 
    $query .= $chk[$i].','; 
    $th .= "<th>".$chk[$i]."</th>"; 
    $fields++; 
  } 
  } 
 $query = rtrim($query,','); 
 $query .= "user"; 
 if(!empty($cond)) { 
 $query .= " where ".$cond; 
 } 
 $query .= " name ".$sorted; 
 $query .= " ".$name; 

 @ $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','userData'); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
echo "Can't connect to Server. Errorcode: ", mysqli_connect_error(); 
exit; 
} 
else { 
echo "Connected successfully<br />"; 
} 

$result = $db->query(stripslashes($query)); 
$numrecs = $result->num_rows; 
echo "Your results: <br />"; 
echo "<b>".$query."</b><br />"; 

echo "<table border='2'>"; 
echo $th; 
for ($i = 0; $i < $numrecs; $i++ )  { 
$row = $result->fetch_array(); 
echo "<tr>"; 
for($f = 0; $f < $fields; $f++ )  { 
    echo '<td>'.$row[$f].'</td>'; 
} 
echo '</tr>'; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: So, you have basically these two questions? 1. What do I need to create to have the program search for a word the user types in (and search in the right catagory)?  2. Also, I want my new results to still be returned in this table, so can I keep any of the table code work i did?   Am I right? Do you need help in the mysql query part? Also, what exactly do you mean by the "table code"?

Comment: yep those are my 2 questions. I (finally!) got the mysql part down. By table code i just meant all my <tr> and <td>, etc.

Comment: Assuming that you have fixed the mysql query part, what is the difference between the result of mysql queries, now and earlier? I guess you are still getting the same result object containing multiple records, each containing some fields.

Comment: Oh, wait. You're saying to change how i want to retrieve my data i needed to change the mysql query from how it is now? In that case, no I haven't changed it/didn't know I had to. I would start from scratch, but i'm not really sure how to get to the point where I am now again...

Comment: @rwqq If you have problems with your PHP code - post it here. If you have problems with your MySQL tables structure - post it here. If you have problems with SQL queries - post them here. Currently your post has only HTML code, which is perfectly fine by itself.

Comment: Yes, I don't think you need to change your query if all you want to do is change the way of posting of category value (checkbox to dropdown). check my answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Finding the entry's, sorting them and choose them by category is a quest which the MySQL is suited for.

So what you'll want to have is a query that uses:

- A [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) on your category-table
- A [`LIKE`-statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) to find the things "like" the users input
- And an [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) to sort them
- Also, you might need to [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in order to sort the items (depends on how you want to sort them).

Answer (score 0):

Your query preparation logic looks a little clumsy.

I suggest you separate your "table code" from the query preparation logic. Prepare the mysql query result object first and then code for the table part. That is the basic of separating the view from the controller logic. Your view code will then not need to be changed when you change the way of preparing the result (controller code).

And assume the database query part as one function (say `getSortedResult()`) which takes the user posted values as a parameter and returns the result object sorted in some order. Decide a format in which to pass the params. Say, you can select multiple values in the category select. Then lets take an array as a param.

Now, you just need to prepare the category param and call the `getSortedResult()`. Print the posted vals, and see what you get,

```
$postedCategory = $_POST['field']; //dropdown's posted values
print_r($postedCategory);
//you may just need to pass this param.
getSortedResult($postedCategory, $_POST['cond']);
```

Now, inside the getSortedResult func -

```
function getSortedResult($categories, $cond)
{
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','userData');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Can't connect to Server. Errorcode: ", mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
else 
{
    //Assuming that you have some category field in the same table. If category is a separate table, you will need to do a join, refer Lukas Knuth's answer.
    $query = "select * from table where category in (".implode(",",$categories)." and somefield = '".$cond."' order by <field you want>";

    return $result = $db->query(stripslashes($query));


}

}
```

Finally in the display logic, loop over the result object and prepare the table -

```
?>
Your results: <br />
<table border="2">
<?php foreach($results as $each) : ?>
    //
    // row preparation
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: hmm..when i run this i get these two errors...any ideas what i did wrong?

`warning: implode() [function.implode]:invalid arguments passed`

and 

`warning: invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: So you are submitting only single value as `field` dropdown's value. In that case it is not an array. verify the $_POST['field']'s value. Add a condition to your mysql query, `if(is_array($categories)) $whereCond = "in '".implode(",",$categories); else $wherecond = "= ".$categories;`

Comment: ok, seriously last question...lol (and thanks so much for your help by the way!) where exactly should this go? Where i put it in still isn't working. Do you have a direct email I can contact you at? I'd be interested in getting your help on another project (for money) if you were interested...

Comment: @rwqq, replied to your mail. By "where exactly should this go?" do you mean the if-else condition I said? It should be put inside the `getSortedResult()` function.